# Chrome menu rendering issue over an image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, rendering

I couldn't find info anywhere, and I havee a very weird issue with Chrome's version 38 update. I have had a dropdown menu that is controlled by JS to add a styling class to a div to make it appear that the menu drops down, never had an issue till the update or in other browsers.

My Issue: 
With JS enabled, after the drop down pops up, on mouse out the menu should disappear, but a portion of the menu stays, and only on top on an image its sitting on top of. If the image is a GIF, then the menu changes with the frames of the gif. If I disable JS and use CSS, everything works perfectly.

Anyone have any ideas with this issue? It seems to be a way Chrome is handling JS

Comment: Just noticed if I enable "Enable continuous page repainting" in dev tools, there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found out this it was a repainting issue with version 38 of Chrome. Doing a workaround to repaint, hopefully it gets fixed.